# Multiple regression on Time Series sensor data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I am working on a regression problem where, I have 12 sensors data (Independent) columns and 1 output column, all sampled at 48KHz. I have total 420 seconds of train data. In test dataset, I have 12 sensor data columns and need to predict output.

Till now, I have tried classical machine learning algorithms without considering time feature. I am new to the time series and not sure if this is actually a time series forecasting problem.

I am not sure if I can consider this as a multivariate time series problem and try LSTM/RNNs. 
I have been following https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/#comment-442845 but not able to understand how I can predict on test data.

Do I need to append a new column to convert test data from (length,12) to (length, 13) and then predict one by one row and use output to next iteration?

Also, is above a correct approach to solve this kind of problem or do I have to think about something else?

**UPDATE**
Updating my question on below comments.
Let's say my train data looks like below (Updated heading just to explain better). I am training LSTM network same as mentioned in above link. I have created Y(t),Y(t-1),x1(t-1),x2(t-1),x3(t-1),x4(t-1),x5(t-1),x6(t-1) using *series_to_supervised* function.

```
                           Y     x1   x2    x3         x4      x5      x6
date                                                                          
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     
2010-01-02 03:00:00      181.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     
2010-01-02 04:00:00      138.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2
```

Now, I have test data without Y column.
As an example,

```
                          x1   x2    x3         x4      x5      x6
date                                                                          
2010-01-02 00:00:00      -11  -6.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     
2010-01-02 01:00:00      -12  -1.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     
2010-01-02 02:00:00      -10  -4.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     
2010-01-02 03:00:00      -7   -2.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     
2010-01-02 04:00:00      -7   -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2
```

What I have done. I have appended fake Y column with 0 padding and replaced first value as *mean of train Y column*. My idea is to use t-1 predicted value in next prediction. I don't know how I can get it easily. I came up with following logic.

Code snippet

```
#test_pd is panda frame of size Nx6
#train_pd is panda frame of size Nx5

test_pd['Y'] = 0
train_out_mean = train_pd[0].mean()
test_pd[0][0] = train_out_mean
test_pd = test_pd.values.reshape((test_pd.shape[0],1,test_pd.shape[1]))
out_list = list()
out_list.append(train_out_mean)
for i in range(test_pd.shape[0]):

    y = loaded_model.predict(test_pd[i].reshape(1,test_pd.shape[1],test_pd.shape[2]))
    y = y[0]
    out_list.append(y)
    if (i+1>=test_pd.shape[0]):
        break
    test_pd[i+1][0][0] = y
```

I have two follow-up question.

1. Is above approach theoretically correct to solve the problem?
2. If yes, then is there any better way to predict on test dataset?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider starting with a simpler approach before going for more complex algorithms like a **LSTM**.

Here in StackOverflow you should objectively ask some doubt about code. So if you share some of your code here, we can try to help you.

Considering that you have a time series like that (example in your link):

```
                     pollution  dew  temp   press wnd_dir  wnd_spd  snow  rain
date                                                                          
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     0
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     0
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     0
2010-01-02 03:00:00      181.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     0
2010-01-02 04:00:00      138.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2     0
```

### simpler approach: MLP Regressor

In a simpler approach, assuming you wanted to predict the pollution, you can build a a [MLP Regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor), so during the training phase, you should separate the data in 7 features(dew, temp, press, wnd_dir, wnd_spd, snow, rain) to predict the pollution. Here an example:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import metrics

data = dataset.values

# integer encode WIND direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
data[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(data[:,4])

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data)

y, X = np.split(data,[1],axis=1) 

mlp = MLPRegressor(learning_rate_init=0.001)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

print (X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print (X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_prediction = mlp.predict(X_test)

print("R2 score:", metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_prediction))
```

Output:

```
R2 score: 0.30376681842945985
```

### in LSTM (You need: 3D [samples, timesteps, features])

**NOW**, Suppose that some feature (wind, air pressure, etc.) at the moment ** t-1 **, ** t-2 ** (1 hour, 2 hours) has some influence on the moment ** t **. So now you intend to solve your problem as a time series by capturing some evolution of wind speed (for example) for some time. So now it makes sense to use LSTM.

So, the function **series_to_supervised** (example of your link) will help you to create new features...

The function **series_to_supervised** has 4 arguments:

- data: Sequence of observations as a list or 2D NumPy array.
- n_in: Number of lag observations as input (X). Values may be between [1..len(data)]
- n_out: Number of observations as output (y). Values may be between [0..len(data)-1].
- dropnan: Boolean whether or not to drop rows with NaN values

So, supposing this series the only one feature X and the label y:

```
                        X   y
2018-01-01 00:00:00     1   2
2018-01-01 01:00:00     2   3
2018-01-01 02:00:00     3   4
2018-01-01 03:00:00     4   5
2018-01-01 04:00:00     5   6
2018-01-01 05:00:00     6   7
2018-01-01 06:00:00     7   8
2018-01-01 07:00:00     8   9
2018-01-01 08:00:00     9   10
2018-01-01 09:00:00     10  11
```

Using this function **series_to_supervised(df.values,n_in=2, n_out=1, dropnan=False)** you will have some like that (I did some improvements in order to understand):

```
                        X(t-2)   y(t-2)   X(t-1)   y(t-1)   X(t)   y(t)
2018-01-01 00:00:00       NaN     NaN     NaN        NaN     1      2
2018-01-01 01:00:00       NaN     NaN     1.0        2.0     2      3
2018-01-01 02:00:00       1.0     2.0     2.0        3.0     3      4
2018-01-01 03:00:00       2.0     3.0     3.0        4.0     4      5
2018-01-01 04:00:00       3.0     4.0     4.0        5.0     5      6
2018-01-01 05:00:00       4.0     5.0     5.0        6.0     6      7
2018-01-01 06:00:00       5.0     6.0     6.0        7.0     7      8
2018-01-01 07:00:00       6.0     7.0     7.0        8.0     8      9
2018-01-01 08:00:00       7.0     8.0     8.0        9.0     9      10
2018-01-01 09:00:00       8.0     9.0     9.0        10.0    10     11
```

So, in this approach we are considering that to predict, we will al least two records X(t-2, t-1) and y(t-2, t-1) to predict y(t), future.

**Why you need to do THIS?** Now I think that I will start answering your question. In a **LSTM** you need to transform your data in 2D in 3D space.

So, after that you need to reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features] before using a LSTM. **So, transform (using this function) your data is just a preparation.**

Answering your question. **You don't need append just one column.** You NEED to transform your data in order to HAVE new features in t-n, t-3, t-2, t-1 to predict some feature in t.

I recommend you follow the steps on pollution case (cited by you) on this blog first, before trying to adapt in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I have updated my question after reading your comments.